# Looking up column in related model

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have 3 tables. Here are they with their columns:

1. **Result**  : id, title
2. **Prospect**: id, result_id, customer_id
3. **Customer**: id, name, address

**Result** *hasMany* **Prospect**.
**Prospect** *belongsTo* **Customer**.
 
**Customer** *hasMany* **Prospect**.

Everything's ok. If I view the **Result**, it would display fine along with its related model **Prospect**.
But in that related model, I'd like to display the **customer name** instead of **customer_id** (by looking up). How to do that? 
And how to paginate the related model?

Thank you so very much!

Answer (score 0):

add in Prospect belongsTo Result and you will be able to get the info both directions.

if you want to do more crazy things like finding results based on customer name then you might need to read up on the following

- [linkable behavior](http://wiki.github.com/Terr/linkable)
- [bindModel](http://mark-story.com/posts/view/using-bindmodel-to-get-to-deep-relations)
- [adhoc-joins](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/view/quick-tip-doing-ad-hoc-joins-in-model-find)

Comment: Hi. Yes, actually I have it baked. Prospek belongsTo Result. 
But still I cannot replace $prospect['customer_id'] with $prospect['Customer']['name'] in my results/view.ctp. Or do I make a wrong call?

So much thanks for the references.

Comment: debug($prospect); and you will see it.

Comment: Yes I have. Still confused & can't get it working but I'll dig into your reference links. Thank you.